# Angular ui router navigates when element is right clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is really annoying, as every time I want to 'Inspect Element' it causes a route change. Or have I done something dumb?

Typical example of directive usage:

```
<a class="dashboard" data-ui-sref="dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

If I right click on that element, it'll trigger the route. How do I stop this?

#### Update

It seems to be only happening in Firefox. My version of FF is 27.0.1.

Comment: According to the docs this isn't the intended behavior (says it should do the browser default for middle and right click) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref

Comment: Not intended behavior. Possibly a browser a specific issue? have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Correct, it only happens in FF. Currently, I'm on v27.0.1

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No, not yet. I've seen the issue you linked to in your answer. Tempted to submit a PR...

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a UI-Router issue, in my case it's an angular issue. Here's the ticket https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2668

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Firefox Right-Click bug in Html5Mode.

- we can use manual bootstraping in angular js app .For example [angular bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manualinitialization)
- works fine when change angular bootstrap code from using.

`angular.bootstrap(document);`

to

```
angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement);
```